# Dota 2 connection problem

Tags: dota-2

I'm having trouble connecting to online games. What keeps happening is its finds a game and lets me go to the loading the disconnects me, it then lets me try and reconnect but it then just disconnects me from the game completely if anyone has any advice I'd appreciate it

Comment: You've done a good job describing your problem, but you've not listed what you've done, if anything, to fix it yourself. Clearly your having connection issues. Test your internet speed, are you loosing packets somewhere, is your connection otherwise stable? ect.

Comment: A log always help. You can make it appear by using the `-console` command-line argument at start up. (Right Click DoTA 2 then go to Properties > Set Launch Options) then copy paste-whatever it prints.

Comment: Is this a frequent problem or it only happened last 2-3 days? I had some similar problems this week-end but was because of the dota servers.

Comment: Try downloading and using steamcmd... it helped me a lot in these kinds of situation.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue last year. It was due to my game not updating correctly..

go to your steam library. right click DOTO 2. 
Go to the properties i believe and click verify integrity of game cache. 
It will do a quick scan and fix whatever problems are giving you any trouble :) 
Just remember, i read it in a doc somewhere that if you dc from the game. the client will tell you so. UNLESS you disconnect at your own will. If you DC with no message then your game is buggy.

Hope this helps you soldier